# Analytical proof of this inequality.

Tags: analysis, inequality

Given any integer $n$, define
$$ f(t) := (2+(n-2)t^2)^4$$
and
$$ g(t) := (n-2)^2t^8 + (n^4-(n-2)^2)t^4.$$

One can easily see that $f(1) = g(1)$.

By doing numerical simulations, I can see that $f(t) > g(t)$ for any real $t > 1$ and any $n \geq 5$. How can we prove this analytically ?

Comment: You do not need an analytical proof; the direct algebraic approach works, too.

Comment: Why $f(1) = g(1) = (n-2) + n^4 - (n-2)^\color{red}{2}$?

Comment: @GNU Supporter, there was a "^2" missing. I edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be $g(t)=(n-2)^2t^8+(n^4-(n-2)^2)t^4$.

If so
$$f(t)-g(t)=(t^2-1)((n^4-8n^3+23n^2-28n+12)t^6+(n^4-25n^2+68n-52)t^4-(32n-48)t^2-16)\geq$$
$$\geq(t^2-1)((12n+12)t^2+(68n-52)t^2-(32n-48)t^2-16)\geq$$
$$\geq(t^2-1)(48n-8)>0.$$